# Quickest way of mapping columns of an array to a new interval

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, transform

I have the following matrix, which represents some points:

```
points = np.random.uniform(30, 50, size = (5,3))
# gives array([[ 45.98139489,  40.27871523,  41.91617071],
               [ 41.1404787 ,  34.56098247,  35.91171313],
               [ 34.46375465,  49.89872417,  39.04753134],
               [ 49.28112722,  32.01837698,  32.83394596],
               [ 48.96623168,  33.58271833,  33.54690091]])
```

Now each column is a coordinate. Each column has values within the range `[30,50]`. I want to map each column to different intervals. I know how to map points from an interval to another thanks to this question: 
[Algorithm to map an interval to a smaller interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931115/algorithm-to-map-an-interval-to-a-smaller-interval)

But I want to make something very fast and that maps each column (possibly) to a different interval. For instance suppose we have

```
intervals = np.array([[0, 10], [3,7], [100,200]])
```

Or we could have them separate in arrays as `xinterval = np.array([0,10])`, it doesn't matter.

**My Slow try**

I collected all the intervals in `intervals` and then used the transformation on each column through a loop

```
for col, interval in zip(range(points.shape[1]), intervals):
       points[:, col] = ((points[:,col]-min(points[:,col]))*(interval[1]-interval[0]) / (max(points[:,col])-min(points[:,col])) ) + interval[0]
```

Where for simplicity I have used the `min` `max` range as the previous interval, but I could have just used `30,50` as such:

```
for col, interval in zip(range(points.shape[1]), intervals):
       points[:, col] = ((points[:,col]-30)*(interval[1]-interval[0]) / (50-30) ) + interval[0]
```

Is there a faster way, without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Straight-forward broadcasting**

Here's one vectorized way making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
mins = points.min(0)
a1 = (points - mins)* (intervals[:,1]-intervals[:,0])
a2 = points.max(0) - mins
out = a1/a2 + intervals[:,0]
```

**Improvement : *Lesser* broadcasting**

Looking closely, we are performing `broadacsting` at few places. Though `broadacsting` is a very efficient method to vectorize things, it still has some cost. We could improve on it, by re-arranging things around with the intention of reducing the number of `broadcasting` steps to just two, as compared to four before.

Hence, the modified one would be -

```
mins = points.min(0)
scale = (intervals[:,1]-intervals[:,0])/(points.max(0) - mins)
offset = mins*scale - intervals[:,0]
out = points *scale - offset
```

I. Broadcasting steps before :

Two at : `(points - mins)* (intervals[:,1]-intervals[:,0])`.

Two at : `a1/a2 + intervals[:,0]`.

II. Broadcasting steps after improvement :

One at `points *scale` and one at the subtraction thereafter .

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def app1(points, intervals):
    mins = points.min(0)
    a1 = (points - mins)* (intervals[:,1]-intervals[:,0])
    a2 = points.max(0) - mins
    out = a1/a2 + intervals[:,0]
    return out

def app2(points, intervals):
    mins = points.min(0)
    scale = (intervals[:,1]-intervals[:,0])/(points.max(0) - mins)
    offset = mins*scale - intervals[:,0]
    out = points *scale - offset
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [104]: points = np.array([[ 45.98139489,  40.27871523,  41.91617071],
     ...:                [ 41.1404787 ,  34.56098247,  35.91171313],
     ...:                [ 34.46375465,  49.89872417,  39.04753134],
     ...:                [ 49.28112722,  32.01837698,  32.83394596],
     ...:                [ 48.96623168,  33.58271833,  33.54690091]])
     ...: points = np.repeat(points, 100000,axis=0)
     ...: 
     ...: intervals = np.array([[0, 10], [3,7], [100,200]])
     ...: 

In [105]: %timeit app1(points, intervals)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.3 ms per loop

In [106]: %timeit app2(points, intervals)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop
```